# return data from a field (column) in telerik gridview using IIF

Tags: c#, .net, telerik-grid

I am using `Telerik Winforms Gridview` and the `Column expression`.

I am trying to return data from a field (column) in a gridview using a `IIF statement`.

The below works:

```
IIF(customer_name='Bills Hairy Mess','win','lose')
```

The below crashes the form:

```
IIF(customer_name='Bills Hairy Mess',cust_ref_1_BOL,'lose')
```

I also tried

```
IIF(customer_name='Bills Hairy Mess',[cust_ref_1_BOL],'lose')
```

cust_ref_1_BOL is a valid field name and is pickable from within the expression editor under 'fields'

Is the above possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can, fairly easy.

You do need to make sure that the field is in the columns list for the grid, which is what I was doing wrong.

It can be not visible, but needs to be there (obviously).

I had a need to exclude some columns from a export but still use them on the screen for calculations, this works fine by setting their visibility to false right before exporting.